# Intersection product of nef and ample divisor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety of dimension $n$, let $D$ be a nef divisor on $X$ and let $H$ be an ample divisor. Does $$D \cdot H^{n-1} > 0$$ necessarily hold?

The context I encountered this is the paper *Fibre space structures of a projective manifold* by Matsushita, where $D$ is the pull-back of a very ample divisor along a morphism $X \to B$ of projective varieties.

Comment: The key feature here is not nefness of $D$ but effectivity (since it’s the pullback of an effective divisor). For example, $D=0$ is nef but of course has trivial intersection numbers. Since $H$ is ample though, it has positive intersecting numbers with all subvarieties.

Comment: For a concrete reference (of much more general statements), you can look at Lemmas 2.3 and 2.4 in ["On the Numerical Dimension of Pseudo-Effective Divisors in Positive Characteristic"](https://doi.org/10.1353/ajm.2014.0047) by Cascini, Hacon, Mustaţă, and Schwede.

Comment: You should look at Nakai-Moishezon criterion (see on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle#Criteria_for_ampleness_of_line_bundles for instance) using effectivity of $D$.

Comment: @DevlinMallory Thanks, that helps :)

Comment: @DominiqueMattei Thanks, that is also what Devlin Mallory noticed.